# Completely remove the author url

Tags: security

I've already removed the login, registration, and password reset stuff. i also removed all links to the author url from single, archive, and index. now i want to remove the actual route so that bots cannot discover the author username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to `.htaccess` file, it will redirect all author requests looking for a number ( Author ID ) to the homepage:

```
#Disable Author Pages
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?author=([0-9]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

---

The PHP / Wordpress way, you could use [Template Redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect):

```
function author_page_redirect() {
    if ( is_author() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'author_page_redirect' );
```

Comment: not what i want. i want to remove it entirely from the wordpress application. i also am not running apache

Comment: @r3wt This does the same thing, nobody knows it exists because it gets 301 redirected back to the homepage, bots don't know, malicious users don't know, nobody knows. It **never** gets to the username portion of the URL.

Comment: **IM NOT USING APACHE** i also want to remove it from the actual application

Comment: @r3wt I'm not sure you can actually remove it as much as you can remove `post` - it's just built into WordPress. Are you fine with modifying core files? By doing so you won't be able to upgrade without finding those files and making the same modifications. Another option would be to use PHP to do the rewrites for you. It may be beneficial to edit your original question and add a bit more detail.

Comment: yes i'm fine with that. I'm a professional C developer and i also am moonlighting into PHP now. I have already made extensive modifications to the wordpress, i just couldn't ever find the routing logic so i'm not sure how that works. I thougt i might be able to find the answer here but oh well. thank you for your time.

Comment: @r3wt After looking through some of the core files, it looks pretty ingrained into WP. I've added `template_redirect` as an alternative solution since you're not on apache.

Comment: thanks a million for your help. accepting your answer as it definitely solved the problem.